# What fabric is suitable for swing repair?

Tags: outdoor, furniture, porch-swing

I have a swing where the fabric provides support for the users. I've looked up "outdoor fabric" but nothing seems strong or structurally supportive. I'm trying to avoid using the straps older furniture used.

What should I be looking for to inexpensively refurbish this furniture?

[image]